# HttpClient - Mapping Json array result with changing some values

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

I have a problem in using the new `HttpClient`.

Before, I was able to map a users Json array into `User[]` by using `reduce`, as the following:

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public userId: number,
        public username: string,
        public password: string,
        public isValid: boolean,
        public type: string,
        public isValidPassword: boolean) {
    }
}

public loadAllUsers() {
    return this.http
        .post('/api/admin/getUsers/', 0)
        .map((res: any) => {
            return new User(
                res.userId,
                res.username,
                res.password,
                res.isValid === 'Y',
                res.type,
                res.isValidPassword === 'Y'
            );
        })
        .reduce((x, y) => { x.push(y); return x; }, <any[]>[]);
}
```

and that is a part of `/api/admin/getUsers/` response:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "username": "Ebraheem Alrabee",
    "password": "827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b",
    "isValid": "Y",
    "type": "admin",
    "isValidPassword": "Y"
  },
  {
    "userId": 4,
    "username": "Sami",
    "password": "827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b",
    "isValid": "Y",
    "type": "user",
    "isValidPassword": "Y"
  }, ...
]
```

I have tried this:

```
public loadAllUsers() {
    return this.http
        .post<User[]>('/api/admin/getUsers/', 0);
}
```

But I still want to use `map` instead of direct deserialize into `User[]`, Because there is values I want to change like `isValid`.

How I can do the same thing with new `HttpClient`, Any one can help?

Comment: As a tiny side note, you can drop both  `? true : false`s from your code as `===` will return either `true` or `false` anyway.

Comment: It is an old code I have to refactor, Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.map` there, to transform/modify `isValid` flag. Also I'd suggest you change `User` class to interface.

```
public loadAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http
     .post<any>('/api/admin/getUsers/', 0)
     .map((res: any) =>
        return <User[]>res.map(item => {
           item.isValid = item.isValid === 'Y';
           item.isValidPassword = item.isValidPassword === 'Y';
           return item;
        });
     });
}
```

Comment: First Thanks for answer, I want to tell you that the `res` is an array  I can't change `isValid` directly

Comment: This is an old code I am still modifying it, Thanks for the note.

Comment: @EbraheemAlrabee' any luck?

Comment: No, `Argument of type '(users: User[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'users' and 'value' are incompatible`

Comment: @EbraheemAlrabee' did you change class to interface?

Comment: It is worked, I just changed the return type to `Observable<User[]>`  because I make `subscribe` later, and add `return` before `<User[]>res.map()`, thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try below, that should work for you without changing user structure , and you just need to modify return type of your function to array of User

```
   loadAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get("apiURL")
        .map(res => {
          return res.json().results.map(item => {
            return new User(
                  item.userId,
                item.username,
                item.password,
                item.isValid === 'Y' ? true : false,
                item.type,
                item.isValidPassword === 'Y' ? true : false
            );
          });
        });
  }
```

as this method returning overvable other end make use of `loadAllUsers().subscribe(data=> this.userArray= data);` - if it works without it leave it or if doesnt work make use of it

---

First of all what you are trying do is `Get` request to get data and you can do like this

you user class will be

```
export class User{
    userId: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    isValid: string;
    type: string;
    isValidPassword: string;
    get isValidPasswordBool():boolean {
       return this.isValidPassword=='Y';
    }
    get isValidBool():boolean {
       return this.isValid=='Y';
    }
}
```

call to http service like as below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, 
             Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

GetAllUser(): Observable<Array<User>> {
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.get("/api/admin/getUsers/",
                       options).subscribe(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to set the `Content-Type` header here?

Comment: @serpent5 - i do set it because it then clear to person who read my code ...and he get info tha return type is going to be json...and help server to provide responseaslo

Comment: But `Content-Type` describes the *request* data, not the response data, doesn't it? Maybe you're thinking of the `Accept` header? It doesn't affect anything, of course - I'm just curious.

Comment: But how I can change the value of  `isValid` to `true` or `false` depends in the server value, Thanks for the response.

Comment: @PankajParkar - sorry i just generated it from external site ..so forget to change it to class updated now

Comment: @EbraheemAlrabee' - updated with proper variable please try that one